# Wordpress .htaccess for hotlink protection does not show Woocommerce email images

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

To protect my Wordpress website images, I added a couple of lines to the .htaccess file in the upload folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://example.com/ [NC]


RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
RewriteRule .(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ - [NC,L,F]
```

Everything works correctly and users who try to visit the image link find a 403 message. However I noticed that the emails sent by Woocommerce are not showing the images, probably due to the rule I added. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite probable that these (web)mail clients are suppressing the `Referer`  header entirely, so you need to permit an *empty* `Referer` in your rule.

However, this will also permit users who directly "visit the image link". But this isn't "hotlink protection". Hotlinking is when the image is embedded in a third party website (on another domain) - and this should still be blocked (most of the time).

For example, modify your rule to allow an *empty* `Referer` header:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://example.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ - [NC,F]
```

(NB: You were missing a backslash-escape before the literal dot in the last rule. And the `L` flag is not required here, since the `F` flag implies `L`.)

However, it's also possible that webmail clients are generating a `Referer` related to (custom) domain hosting the webmail client. You will need to examine the HTTP request to determine what `Referer` is resulting from these requests. Unfortunately, due to the varied nature of webmail clients this could be difficult/impossible to reliably filter.

If possible, images used in emails should be stored in a different "unprotected" location.

Note that the `Referer` header is unreliable at best. Users can choose to suppress the `Referer` header in their browser. And websites can themselves suppress the `Referer` header in modern browsers using the referrer-policy (which would thwart your "hotlink protection" if you permit an empty `Referer`).

Comment: Thanks! That's great, and solve my problem with the email images, but now users are able to visit the image link while I would like to block them from doing that, to make the direct download more difficult. Unfortunately, the images that are sent from the emails are the Woocommerce product thumbnails, so I don't think I can put them in another folder. Any solution?

Comment: "but now users are able to visit the image link" - Yes, that's what I stated above. It's not possible to allow (or block) one and not the other (based on the `Referer`). The request that the email client sends is essentially the same as a direct request the user might make. Realistically, you need to always allow an empty `Referer` since legitimate users can (and do) suppress the `Referer` these days in interests of "privacy".

Comment: It is possible that you could also check the `User-Agent` making the request. Mail clients (Microsoft Outlook, Thunderbird, etc.) should send an identifier in the `User-Agent` header. However, this is very variable as every mail client is different. Users can also change this. Webmail clients may just use the standard browser user-agent. Needless to say, this will be prone to error. For something like a public online store you should not be restricting access in this way as you will catch legitimate users and lose business.